# How do I pass a C# object as the parameter to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

So I have this table which generates it's data based on a collection inside the `@Model`

```
@foreach (var number in Model.Numbers)
{
    <tr class="tb-tnx-item">
        <td class="tb-tnx-id">
            <div class="">
                <span>@number.Msisdn</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-id">
            <span>@number.Country</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-info">
            <div class="">
                <span class="title">Mobile</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-amount">
            <div class="tb-tnx-total">
                <span class="amount"><em class="icon ni ni-coins align-middle"></em>@number.Cost</span>

            </div>
            <div class="tb-tnx-status">
                <span title="@number.Features" class="">@number.Features[0] / @number.Features[1]</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <div class="tb-tnx-status">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doFunction(); ">Default S2</a>
            </div>
        </td>


    </tr>
}
```

And as you can see I have this part right here which calls upon a JavaScript function when I click on it

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doFunction(); ">Default S2</a>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
<script>

    function doFunction() {
        alert("Test");
    }
</script>
```

My question is.. How do I pass `number` as a parameter so that I can do something like this

```
alert(number.Msisdn);
```

Comment: `<a onclick="doFunction('@number.Msisdn'); ">` and then `function doFunction(Msisdn) {
        alert(Msisdn);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should serialize number C# object into a JSON string using **Newtonsoft** nuget Package

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

then pass it to the view as following:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doFunction(@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(number)));">Default S2</a>
```

so final view it will be something like the following:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json


@foreach (var number in Model.Numbers)
{
    <tr class="tb-tnx-item">
        <td class="tb-tnx-id">
            <div class="">
                <span>@number.Msisdn</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-id">
            <span>@number.Country</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-info">
            <div class="">
                <span class="title">Mobile</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tb-tnx-amount">
            <div class="tb-tnx-total">
                <span class="amount"><em class="icon ni ni-coins align-middle"></em>@number.Cost</span>

            </div>
            <div class="tb-tnx-status">
                <span title="@number.Features" class="">@number.Features[0] / @number.Features[1]</span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="text-center">
            <div class="tb-tnx-status">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doFunction(@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(number))); ">Default S2</a>
            </div>
        </td>


    </tr>
}
```

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer doesnt seem to be allowed in .net core projects

Comment: @RileyVarga I have updated the solution to use Newtonsoft.Json package you need to download it from NuGet to your project

Comment: That's what I did too. I must be doing something wrong because when I do this 

function doFunction(model) {
        alert(model.Cost);
    }

it shows an alertbox with "undefined"

Comment: try to log model what you get?

Comment: Oh, it's `cost` not `Cost`. Thank you!